# Successful executed but Time limit exceeded while uploading on codechef

Tags: c++

I have written a code to find GCD and LCM of the number but whenever i submit on codechef it says time limit exceeded. how to submit successfully?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int long long n1, n2, hcf,lcm,tc;
cin>>tc;
while(tc--){
cin >>n1>>n2;
if ( n2 > n1) {   
    int temp = n2;
    n2 = n1;
    n1 = temp;
}
for (int i = 1; i <=  n2; ++i) {
    if (n1 % i == 0 && n2 % i ==0) {
        hcf = i;
        lcm = (n1*n2)/hcf;
    }
}
cout<<hcf<<" "<<lcm;    
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a competition, so it seems like not in the spirit of it to help you too much. But, the issue is that your algorithm is inefficient and takes longer than the site allows (they probably test with very large numbers). Look up GCD algorithms in wikipedia and try again.

Comment: Since your code works, try posting on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

if n is a very large number your **for (int i = 1; i <=  n2; ++i)** will take forever.
Just try to run following simple code.

```
unsigned int  n2 = 4294966296;
for (unsigned int i = 1; i <=  n2; ++i)
{
    int a = i % 10;
}

std::cout<<"its done";
```

It may take forever depending on the speed of your computer.